# How to share a scanner in Win XP over network

Tags: windows-xp, usb, scanner

I use specific software to share my Canon CanoScan LiDE220 between two computers in my house. Use only Win XP.
Can I do that trick without software or hardware with only Windows preferences?

Comment: Just right click the printer then share…

Comment: But I have scanner, not printer

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:
Plug in your scanner’s USB cable to a computer connected to the network or to the USB port of a router or modem. You can refer to the installation instructions specific to your scanner model or Microsoft guide.
Open Control Panel from Start menu, go to Network and Sharing Center and click View network computers and devices.
Right-click your scanner icon and select Install to make it accessible to other machines in the network.